# Change element value based on option select issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the text of a div based on the option select of another div. The script that I have below doesn't work. Can anyone help?

```
<div class="field-wrap">
  <input id="amount" class="floatLabel" name="amount" type="text"/>
  <label for="amount">Fee</label>
</div>
<div class="field-wrap">
  <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
  <select class="floatLabel" name="form">
    <option>Form 1</option>
    <option>Form 2</option>
    <option>Form 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$("[name='form']").change(function(){ 
    if($(this).find('option:selected').text().trim() == 'Form 1') {
      $('#amount').text("450");
    }
    if($(this).find('option:selected').text().trim(); == 'Form 2') {
      $('#amount').text("400");
    }
    if($(this).find('option:selected').text().trim(); == 'Form 3') {
      $('#amount').text("900");
    }
});
```

Comment: 2 cases for you - or add values to "form"-select, or try to get `.text()` instead of `.val()` from "form"-select... And also try to debug your code if something is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your options a value, then use that - there's no reason for a single if, nor for confusing code:

```js
$('#selection').change(function() {
  $('#amount').text($(this).val());
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selection" class="floatLabel" name="form">
    <option value="450">Form 1</option>
    <option value="400">Form 2</option>
    <option value="900">Form 3</option>
  </select>
<div id="amount">

</div>
```

Comment: I actually like this simpler way the most, but it doesn't work on input box. How would I change for it to work on input box.

Comment: Use val instead of text(...)  @ubuntujavy

Comment: `$('#amount').val($(this).val());` <--- if it's an input @ubuntujavy

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
$(this).val()
```

use

```
$(this).find('option:selected').text();  
// you may need to use .trim to avoid white spacses
$(this).find('option:selected').text().trim();
```

**Explanation**

by using `$(this).val()` you will get the value of option that mean your code should be like this

```
<select class="floatLabel" name="form">
    <option value="Form 1">Form 1</option>
    <option value="Form 2">Form 2</option>
    <option value="Form 3">Form 3</option>
</select>
```

but while you didn't set the values for option you need to get the selected option text by using

```
$(this).find('option:selected').text()
```

and for `input` you need to use `.val()` instead of `.text()` so you need to use

```
$('#amount').val();
```

Demo

```js
$("[name='form']").change(function(){
    var option_text = $(this).find('option:selected').text().trim();
    if( option_text == 'Form 1') {
      $('#amount').val("450");
    }
    if( option_text == 'Form 2') {
      $('#amount').val("400");
    }
    if( option_text == 'Form 3') {
      $('#amount').val("900");
    }
}).change(); // use .change() if you need to run the change event on load
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-wrap">
  <input id="amount" class="floatLabel" name="amount" type="text"/>
  <label for="amount">Fee</label>
</div>
<div class="field-wrap">
  <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
  <select class="floatLabel" name="form">
    <option>Form 1</option>
    <option>Form 2</option>
    <option>Form 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @ubuntujavy read the full answer please with explanation .. my code should work with you

Comment: His problem is $('#amount').text("450");

Comment: @PankajShukla you're totally right .. I update my answer

Comment: Didn't work guys. And I have no error under console.

Comment: @ubuntujavy check the demo .. you got `;` error .. please always keep eyes on console

Comment: For some strange reason, it doesn't work on mine. What's going on?

Comment: @ubuntujavy **1-** be sure to include jquery .. **2-** if jquery included wrap the change event in `$(document).ready(function(){ // code here})` .. **3-** and try to use `.on('change' , function(){})` instead of using `.change(function(){})`

Comment: Thanks Mohamed. I add the $document ready and now it's working. This stuff is pretty crazy. One thing goes wrong and nothing work.

Comment: @ubuntujavy that's right sometimes simple code missing make us comes crazy .. glad it helped .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("[name='form']").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Form 1') {
    //$('#amount').text("450");
    $('#amount').val("450");

  }
  if ($(this).val() == 'Form 2') {
    //$('#amount').text("400");
    $('#amount').val("400");

  }
  if ($(this).val() == 'Form 3') {
    $('#amount').val("900");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-wrap">
  <input id="amount" class="floatLabel" name="amount" type="text" />
  <label for="amount">Fee</label>
</div>
<div class="field-wrap">
  <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
  <select class="floatLabel" name="form">
    <option>Form 1</option>
    <option>Form 2</option>
    <option>Form 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Instead of `$('#amount').text("450");`, use `$('#amount').val("450");`.
Similarly do for other options.

Comment: @ubuntujavy Look at the code snippet, it's working. Is there any other details that you possibly missed out?